# Triangle below menu item CSS

Tags: css, menu, css-shapes

My client has provided me with a design for their site and it includes a standard menu with a downward triangle on the active item (see image). I don't know where to start...what's the best way of going about getting this effect?

[image: Active Menu Item]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on generating arrows, triangles and other shapes using CSS: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes

Also have a look at how CSS Arrow Please! generates its arrows: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Here's a little example I just knocked up:

HTML:

```
<div class="active">
    <div>Active Menu Item</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.active > div {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f00;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.active::after {
    display:block;
    content: "";
    font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 0px;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
    border-left: 85px solid #fff;
    border-right: 85px solid #fff;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmf3s97m/